# Multiple Column Height

Tags: tables, two-column, multicol

I need to put three lists of data into three columns. After putting the first set of data this happened:
[image: Table]

But I need all the data to be in the FIRST column only, the next sets of data will go in column 2 and 3 respectively. So far I have this LaTeX code:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols}{3}
Article 1 Sorted by Frequency:\\
e: 323    FREQ:  0.12737\\
t: 242    FREQ:  0.09543\\
o: 232    FREQ:  0.09148\\
...
\end{multicols}
```

What do i write to put the data into 3 columns?

Comment: There's a starred variant of the `multicols` environment that doesn't balance the columns. There is also the `\columnbreak` macro which ends one column and lets you start the next. Having said that I also think that a table might be better suited for the task.

Comment: you need to separate the data that goes into the column by the symbol `&`. So if you want "e: 323" in the first column and  FREQ:  0.12737 in the second column, you need to write: `e: 323 &   FREQ:  0.12737\\ `. If the first line should only contain entry in one cell, you can do that like this: `Title&\\ ` (the second cell will contain nothing in this case).

When you start specifying the content of column2&3 you should automatically see that the data you have entered so far, will only appear in column1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package `longtable`. The only drawback for you probably is that you have to input the data by lines, not by columns, but I dunno.

Remark: Everything with `lipsum` in name is there only to provide some dummy text.

Remark 2: `\endfirsthead` ends the code used for the head on page one. Similar commands `\endlastfoot` (foot on last page of the table) and `\endhead` and `\endfoot` exist (for the "running" heads and foots). They are placed *after* the piece of code to be the head/foot.

Remark 3: You can format the table similarly as `tabular` (adding lines, centering columns etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longtable}{lll}
Col 1 head & Col 2 head & Col 3 head \\\endfirsthead
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c1 & c2 & c3 
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```